# Variable address issue with python functions

Tags: python, memory-address

I'm not sure what to call this issue exactly, but I believe it's best if I just show a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

func_list = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    func_list.append(lambda x: x*i)  # This is just the function of a line with some slope "i"

d = np.linspace(0, 5)

for func in func_list:
    plt.plot(d, func(d))

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I want this snippet to plot three different lines with different slops. Right now, it is plotting three lines with the same slope, and I know why. The value of `i` (which is 3; the last iteration in the first for loop) is the same each time I call `func`.

When I am appending the function to the list `func_list`, how can I force it to use the value of `i` at the time I am appending it to the list? I believe there is a solution using the memory address of `i` instead, but even if I changed the function creation line to this: `func_list.append(lambda x: x*ctypes.cast(id(i), ctyptes.py_object).value)`, it wouldn't change a thing because it would still be using the same id.

Comment: No. Don't even think about memory addresses, Python is a high level, object oriented language.

Comment: Do you have another approach in mind? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Python uses lexical scoping. `i` is a free variable, closed over the `i` created by the for-loop statement. The "correct" way is to use *another* function scope to capture the variable, so something like `def func_maker(i): return lambda x: x*i` then in your loop use `func_list.append(func_maker(i))`

Comment: Alternatively,  although this is kinda hacky, it is a common idiom, you can exploit default values, so you could use `func_list.append(lambda x, i=i: return x*i)`, of course, that changes the signature

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! I didn't know what to call this which gave me a hard time finding an answer. @juanpa.arrivillaga